# "Run-time Error, data for this operation is not usable yet" message from my VB6 program

Tags: vb6

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim dom As New DOMDocument
  Dim http As New XMLHTTP
  Dim strRet As String
  If Not dom.Load("c:\\CH.xml") Then MsgBox "文件不存在"
  http.Open "Post", "http://172.31.132.173/u8eai/import.asp", True '指定服务器ASP
  http.send dom.xml '把xml数据发送服务器端
  strRet = http.responseText 'strRet:返回的xml格式的回执信息
  MsgBox strRet
End Sub
```

The error message, in Chinese:
实时错误
完成该操作所需的数据还不可使用.
translated by google(To English):
Real-time error
The data needed to complete the operation can not be used also

Comment: What's the error number? (`Err.Number`) That will be the same regardless of language, and would let you (and anyone trying to help you) find it on the MSDN site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

("实时错误 完成该操作所需的数据还不可使用" means "Run-time Error, data for this operation is not usable yet.")

The problem is you're issuing the HTTP request as asynchronous

```
http.Open "Post", "http://172.31.132.173/u8eai/import.asp", True
```

which means the `send` method will return immediately even before the server responses.

```
http.send dom.xml
```

but before the server responses you're asking the `responseText` value already. Of course this will cause the runtime error.

```
strRet = http.responseText
```

One workaround is to issue a synchronous request, i.e. change the 3rd parameter of `http.open` to False. A better method is set a handler of `http`'s to handle the readyStateChange event (consult the doc for detail).

Comment: +1. Also, `dom` object is being loaded asynchronously (use `dom.async = False` to make it synchronous or check the `dom.readystate` property).